# NetworkManager-TUI Doesn't Display Interfaces Centos 7

Tags: centos, networkmanager

I did installed NetworkManager-TUI using yum and started it. but once i write nmtui and chooses edit connections, I'm unable to see any Interface. it's just empty at all.

Comment: "Connections" are "profiles", not interfaces. If there is no connection profile, you can add one.

Comment: how to do that?